# Creating commands to run a python software on google colab and jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter, google-colaboratory

I have a python software that is used in simulation and gives output in matplotlib and vtk. Since the process is very gpu consuming, I want to do a few of the simulations in colab. How do I begin working on the process of doing so? Any help would be appreciated very much

I tried copying all of my source code into a separate directory to create an uploadable pypi library that can be imported but it doesn't seem to be working